# Redirect page after signIn - Angularjs and Kinvey

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kinvey

When I try redirect the page to index.html, I get the following error:  $location is undefined.
I just need to redirect to the index page, when the User and Password are correct.

```
 app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$kinvey',  function($scope, $kinvey, $location) {


     $scope.login = function() {

          var promise = $kinvey.User.login({
                username : $scope.username, 
                password : $scope.password
            });

            promise.then(function(response) {
              console.log('User in');
              $location.path('/index.html');

            }, function(err) {
               console.log(err);
            });  
      }

  }
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to add $location in the arguments:

```
app.controller('loginController', ['$scope', '$kinvey','$location'/*here*/,  function($scope, $kinvey, $location)
```